# Android studio print JSON response

Tags: android, json

Hi I am trying to print a JSON response into a readable form that I can then set to a Textview. This is the code where I am trying to print the JSON response.

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    Log.d("json", response);
                    //Creating JsonObject from response String
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    //extracting json array from response string
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    JSONObject jsonRow = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    //get value from jsonRow
                    leaderboardView.setText(jsonArray.toString());
```

it does print the JSON but in a JSON format. this is the JSON format I am receiving.

```
{"data":[{"username":"DolanF","score":"4220","rank":"1"},{"username":"reyay","score":"3760","rank":"2"},{"username":"MeghanG","score":"2570","rank":"3"},{"username":"PrimGosling","score":"1360","rank":"4"},{"username":"JakubRozanski","score":"1190","rank":"5"},{"username":"rodyquigley","score":"1120","rank":"6"},{"username":"Kaz835","score":"800","rank":"7"},{"username":"bailey","score":"570","rank":"8"},{"username":"Ellis","score":"430","rank":"9"},{"username":"Joel","score":"390","rank":"10"}]}
```

my goal is to get the username, rank and score printing in a readable format each row underneath each other.

Comment: Iterate over the items in `jsonArray` -- use `jsonArray.getLength()` to determine how many items there are. Each of those items is a `JSONObject`. Use `getString()` on `JSONObject` to get the `username`, `score`, and `rank` properties.

Comment: Why don't you try `Gson`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
jsonArray.toString()
```

in to:

```
jsonArray.toString(4)
```

Parameter (for example `4` - like above) is the number of spaces to indent for each level of nesting.

You can expect this output:
[image]

Here you have example in Kotlin how you can get all data as variable:

```
fun readJson() {
    val response =
        "{\"data\":[{\"username\":\"DolanF\",\"score\":\"4220\",\"rank\":\"1\"},{\"username\":\"reyay\",\"score\":\"3760\",\"rank\":\"2\"},{\"username\":\"MeghanG\",\"score\":\"2570\",\"rank\":\"3\"},{\"username\":\"PrimGosling\",\"score\":\"1360\",\"rank\":\"4\"},{\"username\":\"JakubRozanski\",\"score\":\"1190\",\"rank\":\"5\"},{\"username\":\"rodyquigley\",\"score\":\"1120\",\"rank\":\"6\"},{\"username\":\"Kaz835\",\"score\":\"800\",\"rank\":\"7\"},{\"username\":\"bailey\",\"score\":\"570\",\"rank\":\"8\"},{\"username\":\"Ellis\",\"score\":\"430\",\"rank\":\"9\"},{\"username\":\"Joel\",\"score\":\"390\",\"rank\":\"10\"}]} \n" +
                "\n"

    val jsonObject = JSONObject(response)

    val jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data")

    var output = ""
    for (position in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
        val row = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position)

        val name = row.getString("username")
        val score = row.getString("score")
        val rank = row.getInt("rank")

        output += String.format("%s - %s (rank: %s)\n", name, score, rank)
    }

    text_view.text = output
}
```

Or in Java:

```
void readJson() {
    String response =
            "{\"data\":[{\"username\":\"DolanF\",\"score\":\"4220\",\"rank\":\"1\"},{\"username\":\"reyay\",\"score\":\"3760\",\"rank\":\"2\"},{\"username\":\"MeghanG\",\"score\":\"2570\",\"rank\":\"3\"},{\"username\":\"PrimGosling\",\"score\":\"1360\",\"rank\":\"4\"},{\"username\":\"JakubRozanski\",\"score\":\"1190\",\"rank\":\"5\"},{\"username\":\"rodyquigley\",\"score\":\"1120\",\"rank\":\"6\"},{\"username\":\"Kaz835\",\"score\":\"800\",\"rank\":\"7\"},{\"username\":\"bailey\",\"score\":\"570\",\"rank\":\"8\"},{\"username\":\"Ellis\",\"score\":\"430\",\"rank\":\"9\"},{\"username\":\"Joel\",\"score\":\"390\",\"rank\":\"10\"}]} \n" +
                    "\n";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        for (int position = 0; position < jsonArray.length(); position++) {
            JSONObject row = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);

            String name = row.getString("username");
            String score = row.getString("score");
            int rank = row.getInt("rank");

            output.append(String.format("%s - %s (rank: %s)\n", name, score, rank));
        }

        text_views.setText(output.toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And output is:
[image]

Comment: Hi, I am trying to get my JSON to print like you have in your Kotlin example, can you create an example in java?

Comment: @PaPaB1nG0 added Java example :)